# Pagination with React-Paginate

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-router

I need to create pagination for list of items with react-paginate. My component is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  }
  onChangePage(page, album) {
    return request("album/" + album.id, {page: page}).then(function(items) {
      this.setState({items: items});
    }.bind(this));
  }

    renderImage(){

        return this.props.images.map((image) => {
            return(

                <li key={image.id}>                 
                        <img alt="job" src={image.img} />
                </li>

            );
        });
    }


    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="albums">
                    <div className="albums_caixa">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <ul className="no_pad">
                                    {this.renderImage()}
                                   <Paginator max={5} onChange={this.onChangePage}/>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        images: state.image

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow );
```

Console shows me error **'request' is not defined** 
I need the following routing-path to my item: /album/:id/page/:page.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

As the console shows, the request method in onChangePage is not defined. Usually in the onChangePage function you need to fetch some data related to that page. You could use other method like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).